# How to : redactor.js imageUpload Post Extra parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, redactor, redactor.js

I am using this awesome editor, but I have no idea how to pass extra parameters with imageUpload and clipboardUpload.

I would like to be able to post extra params when the user past an image into the editor

```
$el.redactor({
    imageUpload: '/WebUpload/Save',
    clipboardUploadUrl: '/WebUpload/Save',
});
```

http://imperavi.com/redactor/

---

## Update

as of Redacor v10 the extra param are included
just use `uploadImageFields`

```
$el.redactor({
    imageUpload: '/WebUpload/Save',
    clipboardUploadUrl: '/WebUpload/Save',
    uploadImageFields: {
                id: 1234,
                name: "test123"
            },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could not find answer anywhere so I hacked the core redactor.js file

I added

```
$.Redactor.opts = {
        imageUploadExtraParams: {},
```

to the options and changed the post to include these params in `pasteClipboardUploadMozilla` and `pasteClipboardUpload`

```
pasteClipboardUploadMozilla: function() {
    var imgs = this.$editor.find('img[data-mozilla-paste-image]');

    $.each(imgs, $.proxy(function(i, s) {

        var $s = $(s);
        var arr = s.src.split(",");
        var data = arr[1]; // raw base64
        var contentType = arr[0].split(";")[0].split(":")[1];

        var postData = {
            contentType: contentType,
            data: data,
        };
        var extraParams = this.opts.imageUploadExtraParams || {};
        for (var propName in extraParams) {
            postData[propName] = extraParams[propName];
        }

        $.post(this.opts.clipboardUploadUrl, postData,
```

and changed

```
pasteClipboardUploadMozilla: function() {
    var imgs = this.$editor.find('img[data-mozilla-paste-image]');

    $.each(imgs, $.proxy(function(i, s) {

        var $s = $(s);
        var arr = s.src.split(",");
        var data = arr[1]; // raw base64
        var contentType = arr[0].split(";")[0].split(":")[1];

        var postData = {
            contentType: contentType,
            data: data,
        };
        var extraParams = this.opts.imageUploadExtraParams || {};
        for (var propName in extraParams) {
            postData[propName] = extraParams[propName];
        }

        $.post(this.opts.clipboardUploadUrl, postData,
```

now I can post extra params just by adding `imageUploadExtraParams` object

```
$el.redactor({
    imageUpload: '/WebUpload/Save',
    clipboardUploadUrl: '/WebUpload/Save',
    imageUploadExtraParams: {
                id: 1234,
                name: "test123"
            },
});
```

---

## Update

as of Redacor v10 the extra param are included
just use `uploadImageFields`

```
$el.redactor({
    imageUpload: '/WebUpload/Save',
    clipboardUploadUrl: '/WebUpload/Save',
    uploadImageFields: {
                id: 1234,
                name: "test123"
            },
});
```